# How to populate a Django form over Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms, populate

I'm trying to create an auto-complete model form on the client-side. I have the auto-complete part down; I can type in a field and have the server return a list of serialized objects (including their primary keys). Now, how do I populate the client-side HTML form with one of these objects? I can iterate through all the known fields in the form (and known members of the object) and insert each one, but surely, there must be a cleaner way.

For what it's worth I'm using JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client-side a Django form is just a regular html form, and since you are using Ajax I don't think that there will be any Django specific way to deal with this. Looping though does not seem like a bad idea. Unless you are hard coding the form field element names in your loop somehow. There should be some consistent relationship between your serialised objects and the form field names of your Django form. This means that you should be able to used JQuery to loop through your form and automatically find the corresponding field value in one of your serialised objects. Select fields might be your biggest challenge if any. You could also look at the field in the serialised object and then find the corresponding form field by its id, and then set its value with JQuery. Django's form element id's generally follow the format id_fieldname I think.